# Running as existing app in node.js Loopback project

Tags: node.js, loopbackjs, strongloop

I am going to take over an existing project developed in node.js with looback framework. I have installed and configured the frameworks correctly and tested by creating a demo application also.
But when I try to run the existing application it is showing an error,

I tried this command to run the project

from the root directory : slc start

Error is

```
Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:8701
```

Any body have knowledge to solve this issue ?

Comment: Is someother application running on port 8701??

Comment: I have checked the port no 8701 is free in my system.